# Need to add a reset button to reset number of passengers saved to 0 but also keeping the text

Tags: javascript

I am creating a passenger counting app which counts the number of passengers allowing it to increment and then to save this on to the screen.

I wanted to add a reset button.so that the saved progress can reset back to 0, while keeping the text.

so when the rest button is hit, it should show the text as previous entries: (blank)

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let count = 0;
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save")
let welcomeEl = document.getElementById("welcome-el")
let myName = "Gull"
let greeting = "Welcome back "
welcomeEl.innerText = greeting + " " + myName
welcomeEl.innerText += ""

function increment() {
  count += 1;
  countEl.innerText = count
}

function save() {
  let counterSave = count + "-"
  saveEl.textContent += counterSave
  countEl.textContent = 0
  count = 0
}

function reset() {
  saveEl = 0
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
<button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">**Save**</button>
<button id="reset-btn" onclick="reset()">**Reset**</button>
<p id="save">Previous entries: </p>

<p id="welcome-el"></p>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

**Expectations:**

where to have the reset function of passengers saved reset to 0.

so the text would appear as Previous entries: 0 or just previous entries: (blank no number shown.)

I have added it so that the reset function via onclick on the html button created. so that when it triggers it should just reset the number to 0.

**Actual result**:

Nothing happens when clicking on the button.

I have tried the following but this removes the text and the resets the number to 0.But does not show again even after clicking on increment and save after reset.

```
function reset() {
      saveEl.innertext = 0
}
```

Comment: when adding the below solution i am getting the following error
    Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText') @timchessish

Comment: You are currently re-assigning the variable with `saveEl = 0`, whereas you probably want to `saveEl.textConent = '0'` (or an empty string) which changes the contents of the `saveEl`.

Comment: Thanks dude that cleared it all up. much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple, change `<p id="save">Previous entries:</p>` to `<p>Previous entries: <span id="save"></span></p>` and in the reset function clear all the record which is stored before.

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let count = 0;
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save")
let welcomeEl = document.getElementById("welcome-el")
let myName = "Gull"
let greeting = "Welcome back "
welcomeEl.innerText = greeting + " " + myName
welcomeEl.innerText += ""

function increment() {
  count += 1;
  countEl.innerText = count
}

function save() {
  let counterSave = count + "-"
  saveEl.textContent += counterSave
  countEl.textContent = 0
  count = 0
}

function reset() {
  saveEl.textContent = ""
  countEl.textContent = 0
  count = 0
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
<button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">**Save**</button>
<button id="reset-btn" onclick="reset()">**Reset**</button>
<p>Previous entries: <span id="save"></span></p>

<p id="welcome-el"></p>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be a span inside the #save paragraph. What you are doing at the moment is setting the contents of #save to "0". It's doing exactly what you tell it to do by replacing "Previous entries: " with "0".

In the HTML ... `<p id = "save">Previous entries: <span id="saveCount"></span></p>`

In the js ...

```
function reset() {
  document.getElementById("saveCount").innerText = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Please use this solution, It's work for you.

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let count = 0;
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save")
let welcomeEl = document.getElementById("welcome-el")
let myName = "Gull"
let greeting = "Welcome back "
welcomeEl.innerText = greeting + " " + myName
welcomeEl.innerText += ""

function increment() {
  count += 1;
  countEl.innerText = count
}

function save() {
  let counterSave = count + "-"
  saveEl.textContent += counterSave
  countEl.textContent = 0
  count = 0
}

function reset() {
  saveEl.textContent = 0
  countEl.textContent = 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>People entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
<button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">**Save**</button>
<button id="reset-btn" onclick="reset()">**Reset**</button>
<p id="save">Previous entries: </p>

<p id="welcome-el"></p>
<script src="index.js"></script>
      <p id="currentTime"></p>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*